# Target a specific td by col class and td class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```css
.col2 .positive {
  background:green;
}
.col2.positive {
  background:green;
}

.col3 .positive {
  background:blue;
}
td{
  border:1px solid blue;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <col class="col1" />
  <col class="col2" />
  <col class="col3" />
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="positive"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="negative"></td>
      <td class="positive"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="positive"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Given HTML above, how do I select all the positive values in col2 in CSS? I used this but it doesn't work.

How to do this?

Comment: `.positive` class is not a child element of the `.col` class  so that your css not work

Comment: col is it within table?

Comment: Here you can't use css like  .col2 .positive{....} . if you have use this then you can put class col1 in tr like <tr class="col2">.. so, your css is working...

Comment: you want to select positive class when it is in second column only ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `td:nth-child(2).positive`.

This will select 2nd `td` elements having class `positive`.

```css
tr td:nth-child(2).positive {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <col class="col1" />
  <col class="col2" />
  <col class="col3" />
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="positive">2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="negative">2</td>
      <td class="positive">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="positive">2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) css selector.

Here is what you could do.

```css
tbody td:nth-child(2).positive {
  background: green;
}
tbody td:nth-child(2).positive {
  background: green;
}
tbody td:nth-child(3).positive {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <col class="col1" />
  <col class="col2" />
  <col class="col3" />
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="positive">Positive</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="negative">Negative</td>
      <td class="positive">Positive</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="positive">Positive</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
tbody td:nth-child(2).positive {
   background: green;
}
tbody td:nth-child(3).positive {
   background: blue;
}
td{
  border:1px solid blue;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <col class="col1" />
  <col class="col2" />
  <col class="col3" />
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="positive"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="negative"></td>
      <td class="positive"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="positive"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```